# task.execute url to bitmap mismatch

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView downloadedimg;
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,void,Bitmap> {


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{

            URL url=new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return mybitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void downloadImage(View view) {

    ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader;
    Bitmap myImage;
    try {
        myImage = task.execute("https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOw5HvydXOAhVKqo8KHYHfAtIQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBart_Simpson&psig=AFQjCNFZSwEG2tjp15Km14uuzEsmZUZ_MQ&ust=1471974330385306");
        downloadedimg.setImageBitmap(myImage);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  downloadedimg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}
```

in the line
myImage = task.execute("some url to image address online");

the complier shows error that

incompatible type

required: android.graphics.Bitmap

found: android.os.AsyncTask "<"java.lang.String,void,android.graphics.Bitmap>

double code infront of java's bracket are not part of statement

@edit Thank you for previous advice i searched and found .get() method 
i used task("").get() to return the bitmap image and code compiled without errors but now nothings happens when i click the download image button

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html - the example and description is pretty sufficient to make you understand the culprit and fix the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask.execute does not return the object downloaded.  It can't, the entire idea of an AsyncTask is that its asynchronous.  Any code that needs to use the result should either be put in onPostExecute (for UI changes) or at the end of doInBackground (for processing data).